# CSS gradient over multiple elements

Tags: html, css, gradient

I was wondering if it is possible to apply a single CSS3 gradient background to multiple elements. In other words, the gradient spans over the parent element but is only visible inside the child elements.

After searching, I found this thread: [Applying gradient over multiple views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447878/applying-gradient-over-multiple-views)

This is exactly my problem, though I need it as `CSS/HTML` code.

To visualize the problem, I made two pictures:

[image: Image 1]

This is the basic setting. The two `<div>`s needing a gradient background are inside a larger `<div>` element.

[image: Image 2]

As you can see, the gradient in the second image perfecly fades from element A to element B.
This effect is easily doable in most image-editing programs, so I could just use an appropriate image to get the desired effect.

However, since images are probably not the best way to solve this, I hope to find an answer here on how to do this with only `CSS`. I used gradients before, but I have not found a solution to this problem on my own yet.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT (06/01/15 13:30 GMT+1):
The Elements A and B should be able to have round corners.
The spanning gradient was originally supposed to be a `radial-gradient`, but it does not need to be.
Maybe the problem is really not solvable.

Comment: How complex are the child shapes you are considering?  In the above example, you could probably fake it by making both child shapes one and adding the middle bar.

Comment: Another idea: It would be a little wacky, but you could probably calculate the necessary gradients with js and apply them manually, based on each child elements' positioning.  Especially if you are thinking a vertical or horizontal gradient.

Comment: How about setting the gradient as the background and using a CSS clipping mask to create the rectangles?

Comment: This might help: http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/

Comment: Found this: [http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/?redirect_from_locale=de](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/?redirect_from_locale=de) still looking through, tho

Comment: done, it seems to support curved borders and if I used multiple `clip-path` on a single element (if possible) it could solve my problem, but looking at the [poor cross-browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) I guess I have to start thinking about an alternative to this.

Answer (score 37):

(Even if this qestion is quite very old...)

Have a look at [Multiple.js](https://github.com/NeXTs/Multiple.js/) - which describes how to apply a gradient to multiple elements **without js**.

Quoted from the demo page:

```
.selector {
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, black);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;  /* <- here it is */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

> [`background-attachment: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) expands background to viewport's size and displays in every element appropriate chunk, exactly what is needed!

The idea behind this is simple as smart and works for most modern browsers (IE8 too).

If applied it **looks like** this:
[image: example]

Comment: I didn't even know about background-attachment! So good.

Answer (score 4):

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/andrewgu/gptbyejt/

One way to accomplish this is that you could always fake it with a **solid background color**. You display the gradient `div` in the background and whatever content `div`s you want, separated with an overlaying `div` whose color matches the background.

*Pros:* Flexible, compatible

*Cons:* Solid background colors only

[image: Method 1]

---

The other way is to use something called [**CSS clipping**](http://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/). You can do this using the CSS declarations of `clip-path` and `-webkit-clip-path`. This basically makes part of an element transparent. However, you need to specify the size of each element beforehand, and tweak it around a bit to get the items to display correctly. This method works with non-solid backgrounds. Contrary to popular belief, CSS clipping is pretty good with cross-browser compatability.

*Pros:* Patterned backgrounds, compatible

*Cons:* Defined child-element sizes, tweaking

[image: Method 2]

Comment: Nice idea! Will the clip-path thing work on elements with border-radius?

Comment: I just noticed the clip example not working in firefox. Does firefox simply not support this?

Comment: Apparently, [clip-path](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) only works in Firefox 33+, and even then only through the `url` parameter, not `polygon`. This means you need to upload a sized SVG file to define the clipping region. It remains completely unsupported in Internet Explorer and Opera Mini.

Comment: @curious, CSS clipping _will_ work on elements with `border-radius` iff you redefine the clipping region to match the element's.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of `background-attachment: fixed` and `iframe` may do this trick for you.
Check out [nexts.github.io/Multiple.js](http://nexts.github.io/Multiple.js) and pay attention to "**How it works**" section