# CSS: Line Up Header and Content Linear Gradient Background

Tags: css, linear-gradients

This question is two fold, one technical and one subjective, here's the technical question first:

I'd like my header gradient to line up with the content gradient so that it looks seamless, so I'd need to have an individual gradient configuration for both. In this example, you can see that if I apply the same gradient to both elements, there's an obvious distinction. Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g73s04vd/

And here's the code I'm using:

```
<style>
.header {
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(159.17deg, #022461 -9.41%, #455c9a 97.45%);
}

.content {
  color: white;
  height:500px;
  background: linear-gradient(159.17deg, #022461 -9.41%, #455c9a 97.45%);
}
</style>

<div class="header">
  This is the header
</div>
<div class="content">
  This is the content
</div>
```

[image]

How do I configure each gradient so that there is no distinction between the header and content?

Update: I need the header to be static in this case, with the content scrolling behind it. Not really sure how to setup a proper example in JSFiddle.

The second question: Since the content would scroll underneath the header, it would look like it just "disappears" since there is no defining line. From an aesthetic perspective, should I even consider formatting my page this way?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a container div around the two divs you have that has the background gradient:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      This is the header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      This is the content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(159.17deg, #022461 -9.41%, #455c9a 97.45%);
}

.header {
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  height:500px;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fraggley/5k1wzsuj/1/

Comment: Wouldn't the scrolling content be visible behind the header in the case?

Comment: Oh i see, your header is fixed? Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791081/css-gradient-over-multiple-elements/38582577

Comment: @fraggly No, I didn't run upon this when I searched, but it looks like this is the same question I asked. Thanks, I'll mark this as a dupe!